# order Notification list in base.html.twig symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm currently working on a symfony project that I didn't start , I'm finishing it so there are some parts that already made by someone else , my question is that in the application there's a nav bar for notification, I wanted to order the notification display by datetime using an attribute but I can't find the controller/action responsible for notification icon I only found the base.html.twig that contains the notification icon what can I do ?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a title="Notifications" href="#fakelink" class="dropdown-toggle"
     data-toggle="dropdown">
    <strong> 
      <i class="fa fa-bell">
      </i>
      {% set conge = 0 %}
      {% set notif = 0 %}
      {% set refuse = 0 %}
      {% for notif_c in notif_conges if notif_c.getEtat == "En cours" %}
        {% set conge = conge + 1 %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for notif_c in notif_conges if notif_c.getEtat == "Acceptée" and notif_c.user == app.user %}
        {% set notif = notif + 1 %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for notif_c in notif_conges if notif_c.getEtat == "Refusée" and notif_c.user == app.user %}
        {% set refuse = refuse + 1 %}
      {% endfor %}
      ({{ conge }})
    </strong>
  </a>
  {% if notif_conges|length > 0 %}
  <ul class="dropdown-menu animated half flipInX">
    {% for notif_c in notif_conges %}
    {% if notif_c.etat == "En cours" %}
    <li>
      <a>Nouvelle demande : "{{ notif_c.motif }}" Envoyée le
        "{{ notif_c.CreatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}" 
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if  notif_c.etat == "Acceptée" and notif_c.user == app.user %}
    <li>
      <a>Votre demande : "{{ notif_c.motif }}" Envoyée le
        "{{ notif_c.CreatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}" a était
        traitée 
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if  notif_c.etat == "Refusée" and notif_c.user == app.user %}
    <li>
      <a>Votre demande : "{{ notif_c.motif }}" Envoyée le
        "{{ notif_c.CreatedAt|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}" a était
        traitée 
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

Comment: Probably using a listener to add notif_conges as a twig global.  Or possible there is a third party navigation bundle.  In any event, just search the entire project for notif_conges to see where it is being set.

Comment: I found it in Twig/UserExtension.php and I added the findBy part, but i'm getting only those who are related to the current user what should I do ?                                                           
                                                               
   $notif_tickets = $em->getRepository('appProjectBundle:Ticket')->findBy(
                array('status'=>'Nouveau'), array('id'=>'desc'));
         $notif_conges = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')->findBy(
             array('user' => $user), array('CreatedAt' => 'DESC'));

Comment: First thing to do is to use the edit link in the lower left corner under your question to add the extension code directly to the question.  As you may have noticed, comments do not format very well.